# Drag Drop to the Desktop after creation of the file? (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, file, drag-and-drop

I have a query about drag-drop in C# using .NET.

My issue is with remote files. I have a list of remote files which the user can drag into an explorer window (desktop, etc). When such a drag occurs I want to be able to download the file and write it to the drop location.

The normal method of dragging files:

```
private void StartDragDrop(string FileToDrag)
{
MyControl.DoDragDrop(new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, FileToDrag), DragDropEffects.Copy);
}
```

...does not suit my needs as I will not have the file data to populate the drag-drop object until after the DROP.

I have seen this functionality in many FTP clients and such.

Thanks in advance wizards.

Comment: I have found the link below, but there must be an easier way to do it than that...

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/DataObjectEx.aspx

Comment: There is no simpler way, .net support for shell drag and drop is limited, so if you want to go beyond the limits you must do all the low-level interoperability stuff.

Comment: There must be some way of finding out the location of the drop, that's all I would require, just the path of the drop, then I could do the work myself and cancel the drag drop.

Comment: Power : have you found the way to find out the location of drop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears there is no logically straight forward method to do such a thing.

But there is a work around (with a substantial amount of work for such basic functionaliy) that can be found at [codeproject](http://codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/DataObjectEx.aspx).

If anyone finds a tidy way of doing it, let me know, I'd be intrigued.